# Networkx has_edge for undirected graph only count once

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have the following graph:

```
full_graph = nx.Graph()

tgt_nodes = ['B','F']

full_graph.add_edge('A','B')
full_graph.add_edge('B','C')
full_graph.add_edge('B','D')
full_graph.add_edge('B','E')
full_graph.add_edge('E','F')

#display and save as img
p = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(full_graph)
p.layout = 'spring'

#p.write_png(outputDir+ version+ '//' + 'cluster_no' + str(clusterNo) + '.png')
display.Image(p.create_png())
```

[image]

I'm trying to find all nodes that are exactly two connections apart, and do things with them depending on the weight.

```
out_graph = nx.Graph()

for curr_node in tgt_nodes:

        #find all paths for curr_node that are <=2
        pot_paths = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(full_graph, curr_node,2)
        print(pot_paths)

        #iterate over all potential paths. If length ==2 either increment weight or add with weight = 1
        for pot_node, dist in pot_paths.items():

            if dist == 2:
                print(pot_node)

                if out_graph.has_edge(curr_node, pot_node):

                    # we added this one before, just increase the weight by one. NEED TO LIMIT SO THAT THIS DOESN't TRIGGER ON INVERSES
                    out_graph[curr_node][pot_node]['weight'] += 1
                    print('incremented edge for '+ curr_node)
                else:
                    # new edge. add with weight=1
                    out_graph.add_edge(curr_node, pot_node, weight=1)
                    print('added edge for '+ pot_node)
```

This should only be triggering one time - in the comparison of B >F, it should add an edge. When it get's to F>B, I don't want it to increment, because it's the exact inverse. Here are my results:

```
>> {'B': 0, 'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'F': 2, 'E': 1}
>> F
>> added edge for F
>> {'F': 0, 'B': 2, 'E': 1}
>> B
>> incremented edge for F

out_graph.edges(data = True)

>> EdgeDataView([('F', 'B', {'weight': 2})])
```

How can I modify so (F,B) and (B,F) over the same intermediary node counts once, not twice?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Actually, here is an example that doesn't work:

```
full_graph = nx.Graph()

tgt_nodes = ['B','F']

full_graph.add_edge('A','B')
full_graph.add_edge('B','C')
full_graph.add_edge('B','D')
full_graph.add_edge('B','E')
full_graph.add_edge('E','F')
full_graph.add_edge('G','F')
full_graph.add_edge('B','G')
full_graph.add_edge('F','H')
full_graph.add_edge('B','H')


#display and save as img
p = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(full_graph)
p.layout = 'spring'

#p.write_png(outputDir+ version+ '//' + 'cluster_no' + str(clusterNo) + '.png')
display.Image(p.create_png())
```

It outputs an edge of 2, when it should be 3 (B & F are connected over G,E, and H)

Comment: What is the value of `tgt_nodes` in your code?

Comment: 2nd line of code: tgt_nodes = ['B','F']

Comment: Note: in your edit, `pot_paths = {'B': 0, 'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1, 'G': 1, 'H': 1, 'F': 2}`.  There's nothing in there that says how many distinct ways there are with that minimum distance.  It just knows the minimum distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You determine the path length based on `full_graph`, yet add the edges to `out_graph`. After adding the (B,F) edge to `out_graph`, it still doesn't exist in `full_graph`. After all, your `out_graph` is initialized to be empty. This is also why your `out_graph` at the end contains only the one edge (B,F).

If your goal is to *update* the original, you should initialize `out_graph` to be a copy of `full_graph` and do all your computations on that. Depending on your needs, networkx's built-in [`out_graph = full_graph.copy()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.copy.html) might do the trick, otherwise you should look into Python's [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Incorrect - (B>E>F) exists in full graph, thus B>F should be added to out graph. The problem is that It is also finding (F>E>B) and re-incrementing B>F. I need a way to track that I've already traversed B>E>F when I get to F>E>B. Think of these nodes as doctors and patients. Doctors can only treat patients, and patient's can only be seen by doctors. I want to know which doctors overlap in their practices, so I look at who is 2 nodes away and add them to the out_graph.

Comment: You're right, my initial answer is incorrect, I now see what you're doing. Your problem seems to be different in nature then: an edge in `out_graph` can only be made if the distance between that pair is 2 in `full_graph`. Doesn't that by definition then mean that whenever it exists in `out_graph`, you're guaranteed to be looking at the inverse of a pair you found earlier?

Comment: If your graph is explicitly bipartite (i.e. consists of 2 sets of nodes that are never connected to eachother directly), you might actually want to look into some of networkx's support for that, such as the [`project_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.projection.projected_graph.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.projection.projected_graph) function.

Comment: You're right - I'll need to go the bipartite route.

Answer (score 2):

So yes, if `G` is undirected, then `G.has_edge(a,b)` and `G.has_edge(b,a)` are both `True` if the edge exists and `False` if the edge doesn't.

So given the way your code is set up, you'll look at each pair of nodes twice and perform the same calculation twice.

How about adding one more condition:  `if G.has_edge(a,b) and a<b:`   (if you are doing this in a case where you could have a self-edge, you might think about `a<=b`).

Then one of the two times it will ignore the calculations.  As long as the nodes have a comparison operation defined, it will work.  So `'A'<1` won't work, but `'A'<'B'` returns `True`.

A warning I should give is that this only works if you're guaranteed to see each edge in both directions, that is, if both nodes appear in your list `tgt_nodes`.  If only the "bigger" node appears, then it won't count it.  So you may need to refine your test for this.

Comment: Thanks - this should work - reading @energya's comment about bipartite - this is an explicitly bipartite graph, so the "correct" way would probably be to use a bipartite-related algorithm, but I'll go with this because it's easier. I was about to add a set of sorted nodes and compare to that, but this is more efficient. The tgt_nodes list are all possible matches to each other, so both would appear there.

Comment: Actually this does not work. It doesn't account for the fact that there may be multiple intermediate nodes. I have edited above to show an example that doesn't work, it shows weight of 2, when it should be 3. The problem is

Comment: If you look at that example, there's nothing I can see in your code that tells it to look at all the different paths between the two.  Once you've chosen `curr_node`, it will only see each `pot_node` once.  So what I've described here solves the issue of counting edges from `a` to `b` and from `b` to `a`, but you'll need to do something different if you want to count the distinct paths.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Energya's request - here is the simple code that works:

```
out_graph = nx.bipartite.weighted_projected_graph(full_graph, ['B','F'])
```